# Does GPU instance on Google Cloud Platform get maintenance after I terminate it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

From the official documentation on Google Cloud Platform, GPU instances get maintenance once in a while:

> GPU instances must terminate for host maintenance events, but can
> automatically restart. These maintenance events typically occur once
> per week, but can occur more frequently when necessary. You must
> configure your workloads to handle these maintenance events cleanly.
> Specifically, long-running workloads like machine learning and
> high-performance computing (HPC) must handle the interruption of host
> maintenance events. Learn how to handle host maintenance events on
> instances with GPUs.

Also, you can get the maintenance alert from google api one hour prior to the instance being shut down, according to the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-host-maintenance):

```
curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/maintenance-event -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

My question is: If I terminate the GPU instance once I get the notification from the api, will the terminated GPU instance undergo maintenance as planned (after one hour) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maintenance only need to restart your app to be applied. In fact, it's, most of the time, one underlying physical element to update/patch/change. The principle is to simply restart your app. WHY?? Because when you restart your app, it restart on another physical component. After all instances restart, the maintenance can be done by Google.

In your case, if the instance is terminated, and you start it, it will start on a "not in maintenance" physical infrastructure, so no impact for you.

*Note: no patch are applied at the software/os level. Google is responsible of the underlying infrastructure (this maintenance), you are responsible of the OS/patching, bellow in the IaaS column*

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  so if the instance is terminated, and I start it, it will start on a "not in maintenance" physical infrastructure. But, does it mean its next maintenance will come sooner than usual? or it does not make a difference on when the next maintenance would come?

Comment: You can't know! First because you don't know when the next maintenance will occur (next week or next day?), and you don't manage the underlying infrastructure. I expect that Google manages correctly the ressource allocation, but I don't know exactly how their algorithms work!